# sqlite3 or CSV files

Tags: python, excel, csv, sqlite

First of all, I'm a total noob at this. I've been working on setting up a small GUI app to play with database, mostly microsoft Excel files with large numbers of rows. I want to be able to display a portion of it, I wanna be able to choose the columns I'm working with trought the menu so I can perform different task very efficiently.

I've been looking into the .CSV files. I can create some sort of list or dictionnarie with it (Not sure) or I could just import the excel table into a database then do w/e I need to with my GUI. Now my question is, for this type of task i just described, wich of the 2 methods would be best suited ? (Feel free to tell me if there is a better one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend upon the requirements of you application and how you plan to extend or maintain it in the future.

A few points in favour of sqlite:

- *standardized interface*, SQL - with CSV you would create some custom logic to select columns or filter rows
- *performance on bigger data sets* - it might be difficult to load 10M rows of CSV into memory, whereas handling 10M rows in sqlite won't be a problem
- [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is in the python standard library (but then, [CSV](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) is too)

That said, also take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which makes working with tabular data that fits in memory a breeze. Plus pandas will happily import data directly from Excel and other sources: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: Let me add that you can use pandas in conjunction with [many IO readers/writers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) to read directly from Excel and write to SQL, CSV or HDF5 if you please :)